# SQLite select query error unrecognized token ":"

Tags: ios, swift, sqlite.swift

I have to update the structure of my exiting table, already done in past. Now, I delete and recreate table to add some columns, but when I query db, I obtain the error -> unrecognized token: ":"
But db and all tables are empty. I don't understand what going wrong.

I'm trying to modify, update code, change query table but obtain the same result.

```
var settings = Table('settings')
if let db = getDB() {
   do{
      try db.run(settings.drop(ifExists: true)) //OK
      try db.run(settings.create { t in
         t.column(id, primaryKey: .autoincrement)
         t.column(Expression<String?>("email"), defaultValue: nil)
         t.column(Expression<String?>("token"), defaultValue: nil)
      })  //OK
      try db.scalar(settings.count) // ERROR
   } catch {
      throw error
   }
}
```

Comment: I've maybe resolved with raw query db.scalar("select count(*) from settings") as! Int64

Comment: I assume the first line is a typo and that you are using double quotes, "Settings"? And when calling `scalar` you need to handle the return value, `let count = try db.scalar(settings.count)`

Comment: Is what I do.....I've changed a little bit code before publish it....however thank you for answer